# Replace Certain Values with NA in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a very large dataset (>500 MB) that I got exported from Snowflake. Snowflake apparently treats `NA` as `\\\\N`. I want to loop through every row/column to replace each instance of `\\\\N` with `NA`.

Example data:

```
df <- data.frame(
          A <- c(1,2,3,4,"\\\\N"),
          B <- c(6,3,"\\\\N",5,9),
          C <- c(2,"\\\\N","\\\\N",5,9)
      )
```

I know I could do a nested for loop, of something like the following:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  for(j in 1:ncol(df)) {
    if(df[i,j] == "\\\\N") {
      df[i,j] <- NA
    }
  }
}
```

but this approach takes an extremely long time. Is there a way to fulfill this in a shorter amount of time?

Comment: (1) Use `=`, not `<-`, inside of the `data.frame`, since `<-` is assigning name vectors in the global environment and *not named* vectors in the frame. (2) You most certainly don't have a mixed vector of numbers and the string `"\\\\N"`, so you will need to deal with this later. (You may know that with this example.) (3) `df[] <- lapply(df, function(z) replace(z, z == "\\\\n", NA))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do:

```
colnames(df) <- LETTERS[1:3] #To assign colnames propertly
```

Followed by:

```
df[df=="\\\\N"] <- NA
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
df
     A    B    C
1    1    6    2
2    2    3 <NA>
3    3 <NA> <NA>
4    4    5    5
5 <NA>    9    9
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `replace` + `type.convert`

```
> type.convert(replace(df,df=="\\\\N",NA),as.is = TRUE)
   A  B  C
1  1  6  2
2  2  3 NA
3  3 NA NA
4  4  5  5
5 NA  9  9
```